# How do I Raise Money for my small Business?

Tags: software-industry, management, startup

I own a very small Business and managed to publish a handful of mobile Games and Apps.
I basically do everything on my own and pay small fees to freelancers for extra design, code, etc. Simply put I haven't made enough money to hire developers. I have some good ideas but need help and more people for that.

I tried working with some friends in the past but couldn't manage to get anything out of it because it was not easy to reach an agreement and people wouldn't do their tasks on time and also I didn't have much experience back then. *(We had a lot of management problems.)*

I know that it's a somewhat general topic but I need guidelines and personal experience on this. So how do I approach this? How should I get more funds for my Ideas and projects?
Is it a good Idea to Team up with people online and not having a detailed contract?
I live in U.S at the moment.

Comment: Sorry to say that your question does not belong on Workplace SE. Here we answer very specific workplace interactions related questions, not give advice on how to grow your business.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we don't give advice on how to grow a business.

Comment: This could have gone on startup.se but it shut down

Comment: Do you have a rich aunt?

Answer (score 2):

I could not tell better than this picture:

[image]

Comment: It all just seems so easy!